# Shortcut for deleting a line in texmaker

Tags: texmaker, keyboard

I could do

- **triple-click on a line**
- and then **cmd + X**

but is there a simpler solution? Like in Notepad++ **Ctrl + L**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut for deleting a line.
I use the "pos1" and "end" functionality of the keyboard to select the whole line and then just hit backspace or delete.
This way i don't have to use the mouse to select the line.

On a mac that would be

- cmd + arrow right
- cmd + shift + arrow left
- backspace

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is sad. Then I will stick to use cmd + arrow left followed by shift + down followed by backspace.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows and probably Linux:

1. Home    OR   End

Place the cursor at the beginning or end of the line

2. Shift + arrow down OR Shift + arrow up

Depending on the selection previously done in 1. press Shift + arrow down if the cursor position is the line's start (key Home) or Shift + arrow up if at the line's end (key End) to select the line. Once the line is selected one can cut or delete the selection

3. Control + X (cut) OR Backspace (delete)

If there was the option to change the keybindings, as in Overleaf, the operation would be dd  for Vim keybindings which is convenient.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That was already mentioned in the other answer ...